# Filtering MongoDB data in controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have this snippet of code in my controller but I'd like to filter the incoming records by a field `archived == true` in the MongoDB document.

Here is the filterless code that works right now. I'm not sure where to add the filter. I tried adding a simple `filter()` using prototype but it broke. What am I missing?

```
var Candidate = require('../models/candidate');
var async = require('async');

// Display list of all Candidate
exports.candidate_list = function(req, res, next) {

  Candidate.find({})    //should something go in between the {}?
    .sort([['name', 'ascending']])
    .exec(function (err, list_candidates) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      //Successful, so render
        res.render('candidate_list', { title: 'Candidates', list_candidates:  list_candidates});
    });

};
```

Comment: `Candidate.find({archived:true})`

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for making me feel dumb.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var Candidate = require('../models/candidate');
var async = require('async');

// Display list of all Candidate
exports.candidate_list = function(req, res, next) {

      Candidate.find({achived:true}) 
        .sort([['name', 'ascending']])
        .exec(function (err, list_candidates) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
          //Successful, so render
            res.render('candidate_list', { title: 'Candidates', list_candidates:  list_candidates});
        });

    };
```